# Setting up SSH (SFTP) on Windows Server: server refused our key

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh, ssh-keys

I'm trying to set up OpenSSH on a Windows server to test SSH.NET but I need to authenticate using a key, rather than a password, and I'm having problems doing so.

I can login to the OpenSSH server via PuTTY using a username and password, but when I set up the private key in PuTTY, I keep getting error: `Server refused our key`

My steps:

- **Windows Server:**

  1. Installed OpenSSH server
  2. Started OpenSSH server and Agent services
  3. Copied the public key within PuTTY's Key Generator textbox on my workstation into `%UserProfile%\.ssh\authorized_keys`

     - I found [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_PuTTY) article, but it's about connecting to a Linux server and using commands such as `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`; I'm not sure whether it could be related to this or if this should be done on a Windows server.
  4. Restarted OpenSSH server and Agent
- **Workstation:**

  1. Installed PuTTY on my workstation
  2. Ran PuTTY Key Generator and generate public and private keys
  3. Saved my public and private keys
  4. Opened PuTTY and added the private key file under the SSH|Auth section
  5. Clicked Open, received error `Server refused our key`, and am prompted for the password

Any suggestions/ideas?

---

- **`sshd_config`:**

  ```ini
  # This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.
  # See sshd_config(5) for more information.

  # The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
  # OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where possible,
  # but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the default value.

  # override default of no subsystems
  Subsystem sftp              sftp-server.exe

  # Logging
  SyslogFacility              LOCAL0
  LogLevel                    DEBUG3

  # The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
  # but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
  AuthorizedKeysFile          .ssh/authorized_keys

  Match Group                 administrators
    AuthorizedKeysFile        __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys

  #Port                        22
  #AddressFamily               any
  #ListenAddress               0.0.0.0
  #ListenAddress               ::

  #HostKey                     __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
  #HostKey                     __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
  #HostKey                     __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
  #HostKey                     __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

  # Ciphers and keying
  #RekeyLimit                  default none

  # Logging
  #SyslogFacility              AUTH
  #LogLevel                    INFO

  # Authentication:
  #LoginGraceTime              2m
  #PermitRootLogin             prohibit-password
  #StrictModes                 yes
  #MaxAuthTries                6
  #MaxSessions                 10

  #PubkeyAuthentication        yes

  #AuthorizedPrincipalsFile    none

  # For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
  #HostbasedAuthentication     no

  # Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for HostbasedAuthentication
  #IgnoreUserKnownHosts        no

  # Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
  #IgnoreRhosts                yes

  # To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
  #PasswordAuthentication      yes
  #PermitEmptyPasswords        no

  # GSSAPI options
  #GSSAPIAuthentication        no

  #AllowAgentForwarding        yes
  #AllowTcpForwarding          yes
  #GatewayPorts                no
  #PermitTTY                   yes
  #PrintMotd                   yes
  #PrintLastLog                yes
  #TCPKeepAlive                yes
  #UseLogin                    no
  #PermitUserEnvironment       no
  #ClientAliveInterval         0
  #ClientAliveCountMax         3
  #UseDNS                      no
  #PidFile                     /var/run/sshd.pid
  #MaxStartups                 10:30:100
  #PermitTunnel                no
  #ChrootDirectory             none
  #VersionAddendum             none

  # no default banner path
  #Banner                      none

  # Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
  #Match User                  anoncvs
  #  AllowTcpForwarding        no
  #  PermitTTY                 no
  #  ForceCommand              cvs server
  ```
- **Log:**

  ```
  debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 3 IPV6_V6ONLY
  debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
          Server listening on :: port 22.
  debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
          Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
  debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
  debug3: spawning "E:\\ssh\\OpenSSH-Win64\\sshd.exe" -R
  debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 291
  debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
  debug3: send_rexec_state: done
  debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 4, 4
          Connection from x.x.x.72 port 53482 on x.x.x.x port 22
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version WinSCP_release_5.17.6
  debug1: no match: WinSCP_release_5.17.6
  debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug3: spawning "E:\\ssh\\OpenSSH-Win64\\sshd.exe" -y
  debug2: Network child is on pid 7688
  debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 6 config len 291
  debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
  debug3: send_rexec_state: done
  debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
  debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
  debug3: preauth child monitor started
  debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
  debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
  debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
  debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
  debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
  debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
  debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
  debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,rsa2048-sha256,rsa1024-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
  debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
  debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128 [preauth]
  debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-ctr,blowfish-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128 [preauth]
  debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
  debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
  debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
  debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
  debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org [preauth]
  debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
  debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none [preauth]
  debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none [preauth]
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
  debug3: receive packet: type 30 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_sshkey_sign entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_sshkey_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
  debug3: mm_answer_sign
  debug3: mm_answer_sign: KEX signature 000000EAA5308050(83)
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
  debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
  debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
  debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
  debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
  debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
  debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
  debug1: KEX done [preauth]
  debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
  debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
  debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
  debug1: userauth-request for user myuser@mycompany.com service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
  debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
  debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
  debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 291
  debug3: checking match for 'Group administrators' user mycompany\\myuser host x.x.x.72 addr x.x.x.72 laddr x.x.x.x lport 22
  debug3: lookup_principal_name: Successfully discovered explicit principal name: 'mycompany\\myuser'=>'myuser@mycompany.com'
  debug3: LsaLogonUser Succeeded (Impersonation: 0)
  debug1: user mycompany\\myuser matched group list administrators at line 89
  debug3: match found
  debug3: reprocess config:90 setting AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
  debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
  debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
  debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for myuser@mycompany.com [preauth]
  debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
  debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
  debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=
  debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
  debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
  debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 58.995ms, delaying 50.873ms (requested 6.867ms) [preauth]
  debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
  debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
  debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
  debug1: userauth-request for user myuser@mycompany.com service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
  debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
  debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey [preauth]
  debug2: userauth_pubkey: valid user myuser@mycompany.com querying public key ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza2EAAAABJQAAAQEAoTH5Dd4wzYkYr6WT/IeK+Lwy33KCHXJMxBvKrnaiLq8zamuKSibwu7xn5TUac2ZWXnQ== [preauth]
  debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg ssh-rsa pkblob RSA SHA256:ERmTsG3EdOUU6A5/1iqPYX3+E3aTF5Ke+5zOs [preauth]
  debug3: mm_key_allowed entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 22 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_key_allowed: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYALLOWED [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 23 [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug3: monitor_read: checking request 22
  debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed entering
  debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key_from_blob: 000000EAA53A75C0
  debug1: trying public key file __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
  debug3: Bad permissions. Try removing permissions for user: NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users (S-1-5-11) on file C:/ProgramData/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys.
          Authentication refused.
  debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: RSA key is not allowed
          Failed publickey for myuser@mycompany.com from x.x.x.72 port 53482 ssh2: RSA SHA256:ERmTsG3EdOUU6A5/1iqPYX3+E3aTF5Ke+5zOs
  debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
  debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 0 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
  debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
  debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 2.030ms, delaying 4.837ms (requested 6.867ms) [preauth]
  debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
  debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
  debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
  debug1: userauth-request for user myuser@mycompany.com service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
  debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
  debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
  debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
  debug1: auth2_challenge: user=myuser@mycompany.com devs= [preauth]
  debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices '' [preauth]
  debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices  [preauth]
  debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
  debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.000ms, delaying 6.867ms (requested 6.867ms) [preauth]
  debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
  debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
          Connection closed by authenticating user myuser@mycompany.com x.x.x.72 port 53482 [preauth]
  debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
  debug3: mm_request_receive entering
  debug1: do_cleanup
  debug1: Killing privsep child 7688
  ```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an administrator account? What are the current file permissions of the `authorized_keys` file?

Comment: And it's `c:\users\myuser\.ssh` not `c:\users\myuser.ssh` (though I assume it's a typo only). + For Win32-OpenSSH specific instructions, see my guide at https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server#key_authentication

Comment: @user1686 As suggested in a post, I've removed all users allowed to access this file except for myself and I've got full permission on this file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for highlight it. I've fixed it. Not a typo, but somehow, it needed a \\ because the folder started with a full stop. Odd but fixed :), oh,, and I'll check your guide now. Thanks

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I've just ran the cmd you suggested to find all the host keys and I'm getting "permission denied" on the 4 entries returned. Note that I didn't install OpenSsh in my System32 but on my E drive in E:\SSH\OpenSSH-Win64. Is this a requirement? I've also added that path to the machine PATH environment. I've checked the permission on this folder and I have Authenticated Users, SYSTEM, local admin, and local users. Should I change something?

Comment: Ah, so you installed it separately instead of using the one that's bundled with Windows? Did you install the "official" MS build or did you get it from elsewhere?

Comment: If you refer to the `for %f in ... ssh-keygen.exe  ...` command – That's for server host keys – that has nothing to do with your authentication problem.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ok, fair! I'm running this command on the server alright but I thought I'd mention it since it was one of the steps in the article.

Comment: @user1686 I downloaded it from https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases

Comment: You didn't answer, if you are using an account in Administrators group.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I'm a local admin to the machine but not part of the domain admin group.

Comment: Domain is not relevant here. If you are a local administrator, then you need to use a different authorized keys file. Read the link I have posted before.

Comment: I've added my key to "administrators_authorized_keys" in "%ProgramData%\ssh" but I'm still being prompted for a password and also still getting the message: "Server refused our key" in WinSCP. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you post your sshd (server) config file, and your log files from the server?

Comment: @user1173240 See update above. I've added the config as requested. Couldn't find any logs. I can see a logs folder in "%programdata%\ssh\logs" but that's empty. Still googling where to find these on a windows server.

Comment: @user1173240 I've found out how to enable the logs and I've updated my question. Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: Increase the logging verbosity to `DEBUG3` and post the server logs again. We can see the authentication is being refused. However, the reason isn't clear exactly.

Comment: @user1173240 I've updated the logs section in the question. Couple of things are showing up which will hopefully help.

Comment: @user1173240 It's sorted! I removed the "Authenticated Users" as suggested. Got a bunch of errors while doing so but it was still applied on the ssh folder and the second I did that, I was able to login using the key file! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Check permissions on the `administrators_authorized_keys`. This file should only be accessible by `SYSTEM` and `Administrators` group.

Comment: @Thierry Glad to know the problem is solved. Happy SSH'ing.